# Code snippet management

Tags: project-management

I am wondering if there exists a professional approach or standard for manage source code snippets (I don't mean versioning like svn or GIT)

I heard about compozer, but that seems to be more focused on dependencies management.

It there a professional approach for creating a code library for code/class reusability

Comment: It's called exactly that, a library.

Comment: Yes ok, but asume that there are multiple was to create such a library  e.g: I simply create a folder structure where I store my source code. Or is there "professional software" that allows me to categorize and search my code library? I asume that there already must be a structured/professional way of dealing with source code management...

Comment: How to make a library is different from language to language, there is no general, one-above-all method. The question as it is seems to be too broad, it would likely be better if you asked about a specific language.

Comment: Mmh ok thats new for me, I just though of one system for storing multiple language snippets. So why would you use a different approach "per language"? I understand that snippets of languages supporting classes could be more easily to store as HTML snippets, but even then.. snippets are snippets. I work on multiple languages so I would like one way of storing their snippets. So what are the general approaches for storing code snippets and why would you use different approaches per language type?

Comment: Two key aspects to consider here: 1) Different languages have different import mechanisms and layouts, unless you want to just copy-paste your code in you need to keep snippets in a different structure depending on the language. 2) Mostly you're writing in one language at a time. Meaning that if you're working with, say, Java you won't need snippets from your C snippet collection.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, on aspect #1 I more or less agree, but I dont agree on #2 because for example I would like to access my snippets library for HTML, CSS, PHP, JQuery/Js at the same time on the same project, and secondly if you have a implementation for dealing with a certain task in JAVA I would like to look into it while coding C# because I can learn from it while dealing with a similar situation in C#...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about project management, which, per the [project-management] tag, is now off-topic.  See http://pm.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am prefer to use the `Gist Box` plugin in Chrome. [The gist box can be found here](http://www.gistboxapp.com/).

- [Gistbox Clipper, @Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gistbox-clipper/cejmhmbmafamjegaebkjhnckhepgmido)
- [Gistbox, @Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gistbox/caoihfibgoiiakncomhccbflmlgjaohf)

Answer (score 2):

I use http://www.int64.io

It's an online snippet manager which allows you to save snippets, organize them by different boards (like folders), give them tags (you can use pre-defined or create your own). There are tags for different languages, so you can keep different snippets in one place without confusing them.

Search will be implemented in about a month as well.

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of http://www.int64.io

Comment: thank you, looks promising! :)

Comment: That link doesn’t work for me.  I get “Server not found”.

Comment: Unfortunately, that service has folded.